# not able to launch UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to launch the FriendsController(UICollectionViewController) from appdelegate with the following code:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let friendsController = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout:  layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: friendsController)
```

Here is what FriendsController.swift looks like, you can try it yourself and see that it does work:

https://gist.github.com/naderahmedtao/c64d09a3ca62549a015d8df62842b53f

But, now I want to launch FriendsController from a ViewController but nothing happens.

Here is what I have tried:

```
let friendsController = FriendsController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(friendsController, animated: true)
```

I also tried this:

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
   navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

I expected FriendsController to launch from the VC, but it does not, it only works from appdelegate.

UPDATE: I just verified that navigationController is nil ! However, I do not want to launch the hosting VC from appdelegate because it is attached to the storyboard... is there any solution?

Comment: Verify `navigationController?` is `non-nil`.

Comment: yes you are correct.. navigationController is nil !  what should i do now ?

Comment: Just wanted to know if you have remote work as i was looking for some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a navigation for the first vc in `AppDelegate` for `navigationController?` not to be `nil` like

```
let vc = FirstVC()
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

After that do

```
let friendsController = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

---

Select the vc , then from Editor

[image]

---

You can also load it like

```
 let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstID") as! FirstVC
 window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

Comment: but i cant launch FirstVC from appdelegate, is there any way around this ?

Comment: the reason is because FirstVC is attached to a ViewController within a storyboard, and has outlet connections with that VC in the storyboard, therefore it can not be launched independently or

Comment: select the firstvc in IB and from Editor menu select Embed in navigation

Comment: my apologies but i am new to IOS development, can you provide me baby steps by step instructions on what you mean

Comment: thanks it worked...can you provide some details as to why it needs this navigation controller ?  also ... are you available for some side-work? maybe 15-20 hours a week.. u can work from home